# Mathematical Induction proof classical logic tautologies

Tags: logic

I need to prove through mathematical induction that a logic L (Łukasiewicz) does not contain all tautologies of classical logic. I get that to start you show the contrapositive, and then start with base cases propositions with connectives. But I have no idea how to show why mathematical induction does not work for Łukasiewicz logic...

Answer (score 2):

To prove the claim you only need to present some tautology of classical logic, which is not a tautology of Łukasiewicz. Such an example can be the law of excluded middle $A\vee\neg A$ or the contraction axiom $(A\to(A\to B))\to (A\to B)$. Why would someone want to use an inductive argument here?